# Compiler is showing me this error : struct.error: ushort format requires 0 <= number <= USHRT_MAX

Tags: python, sockets, numpy, video-streaming

client.py

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import socket
import sys
import pickle
import struct 
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
clientsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost',5000))
while True:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    data = pickle.dumps(frame) 
    clientsocket.sendall(struct.pack("H", len(data))+data)
```

The error is in the last line.

> Error :  struct.error: ushort format requires 0 <= number <= USHRT_MAX.

Comment: Is there anything to be confused about? Clearly, `len(data) > USHRT_MAX`. A quick google would show you that `USHRT_MAX == 65535`

Comment: Thanks, but where should i edit to get this code working?

Comment: Make your data shorter (lower camera resolution), or encode a larger integer in `struct.pack`

Answer (score 0):

modify "H" with "L" both on client and server. should work

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this answer, please?